# Memory overflow during inference in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras

I have written these functions to carryout inference using the saved weights of a trained binary classifier. I have about 120k images to make inference. But the GPU freezes after getting to 82k images. Please is there anything I need to fix in my code to resolve this memory issue. Could the model be saving the checkpoints for the forwards pass nodes during each instance of inference? Please folks I need this fixed urgently, I have a huge number files to urgently sort.

```
def fully_frozen_MobileNetV2(inference = False, n_class=2):
    image_size = 192
    image_channels = 3
    IMG_SHAPE = (image_size, image_size, image_channels)

    # Create the base model from the pre-trained model MobileNet V2
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')

    base_model.trainable = False

    #create the top layers
    global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
    prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_class)

    #add the top layers 
    model_fully_frozen = tf.keras.Sequential([
      base_model,
      global_average_layer,
      prediction_layer
    ])

    if inference:
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001) 
   compute_loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True) 
        compute_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
        model_fully_frozen.compile(optimizer, loss=compute_loss, metrics= 
    [compute_accuracy])

    return model_fully_frozen



def read_and_preprocess_single_image_from_path(single_path, 
    image_size=192, image_channels=3):
    #first read the image file
    img_raw = tf.io.read_file(single_path)
    image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img_raw, channels=image_channels)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [image_size, image_size])
    image /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range
    return image


def get_path_list(path_to_image_folder):
    data_root = pathlib.Path(path_to_image_folder)
    #merge the folders, create a list of image paths and randomize
    image_paths = list(data_root.glob('*/*'))
    image_paths = [str(path) for path in image_paths]
    return image_paths


def classify_and_collect_images_with_bags(model, path_to_image_folder, 
    destination_folder, prnt_progr=True):
    path_list = get_path_list(path_to_image_folder)
    counter = 0
    paths_of_images_with_bags = []
    for path in path_list:
        #create a single batch from the path
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([path])
        dataset = 
dataset.map(read_and_preprocess_single_image_from_path).batch(1)
        image_class = np.argmax(model.predict(dataset))
        print(image_class) ### test only
        if int(image_class) > 0:
            copy_files(path, destination_folder)
            paths_of_images_with_bags.append(path)
        #print progress after each 1k steps if prnt_progr is true   
        counter+=1
        if prnt_progr and counter%1000==0:
            print(counter)
    return paths_of_images_with_bags


def copy_files(path, destination_folder):
    #import shutil
    shutil.copy(path, destination_folder)
    return None
```

Make inference using images in the `in_folder` and copy files belonging to `class 1` into the `out_folder`.

```
classify_and_collect_images_with_bags(classifier, 'in_folder', 'out_folder')
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a work around for this issue. I had to break `classify_and_collect_image_with_bags` into these 3 simpler functions:

```
def create_inference_dataset(image_paths):
    inference_dataset =tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_paths)
    inference_dataset = 
inference_dataset.map(read_and_preprocess_single_image_from_path).batch(1)
    return inference_dataset

def classify_single_image(model, single_batch):
    image_class = int(np.argmax(model.predict(single_batch)))
    return image_class

def classify_and_collect_images_with_bags(model, path_to_image_folder, 
destination_folder, prnt_progr=True):
    counter = 0
    #collect image paths into a list and inference create dataset
    path_list = get_path_list(path_to_image_folder)
    inference_dataset = create_inference_dataset(path_list)
    start_time = time.time()
    for batch, path in zip(inference_dataset, path_list) :
        image_class = classify_single_image(model, batch)
        if image_class > 0:
            #print(path)
            copy_files(path, destination_folder)
        counter+=1
        if prnt_progr and counter%1000==0:
            duration = time.time() - start_time
            print(counter, duration)
```

Rather than creating a new tf.dataset for each image, I created a single dataset with `bs = 1`and iterated through it. With this solution, inference was done one instance at a time for each batch.

Aside from solving the memory issue, the inference time was also reduced from 75s/1000 images to 20s/1000 images.

I trust there's a better solution to this issue the though, I do not believe creating multiple tf.dataset inside a loop would ground a GPU.